# How to extract data using Ical.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, icalendar

I have an ics file I want to read data out from. I downloaded Ical.Net using Nuget and I'm trying to figure out how to work with it. All I want to do is get the same info as I would get if I uploaded my ics file to this website: https://icsconvert.appspot.com/

Which is, for each "event":

- Summary
- Description
- Start
- End
- Location

But I don't understand how I can get that info out of the file. Here's what I have so far:

```
string filepath = @"C:\My\file\path\myIcs.ics";
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filepath);
string content = file.ReadToEnd();
file.Close();

Ical.Net.Calendar calendar = Ical.Net.Calendar.Load(content);

foreach (var c in calendar.RecurringItems)
{
    // 1. Do something!
    // 2. ????
    // 3. Profit!
}
```

Here's a sample file I got from [here](https://gist.github.com/DeMarko/6142417):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Access-A-Ride Pickup
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20130802T103400
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20130802T110400
LOCATION:1000 Broadway Ave.\, Brooklyn
DESCRIPTION: Access-A-Ride trip to 900 Jay St.\, Brooklyn
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:3
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:Pickup Reminder
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Access-A-Ride Pickup
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20130802T200000
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20130802T203000
LOCATION:900 Jay St.\, Brooklyn
DESCRIPTION: Access-A-Ride trip to 1000 Broadway Ave.\, Brooklyn
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:3
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT10M
DESCRIPTION:Pickup Reminder
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

How can I get the data I want? I want to use the foreach to save that data into a custom list.

Comment: as far as I can see you just have a set of two events there, not recurring events (as in defined with an RRULE). Doesn't `calendar.Events` contain them, perhaps? (I've never used this library, just had a quick poke at the source code and it looks like the calendar class has an "Events" property. If not, take a look using Intellisense to see what it does have, that you could use.

Comment: If it turns out there is something in the RecurringEvents collection, then again use intellisense to see what fields are in `c` and then you can see what info you can get out.

Comment: @ADyson You gotta be effing kidding me... I'm such an idiot. Yes, I should've used Events instead of RecurringItems (I completely misunderstood what that meant), now it correctly auto completes the things I need. This might be the fastest time anyone has managed to help me with my problem! :D Feel free to add an answer and I'll give you the holy green checkmark.

Comment: Done...thankyou. Glad it resolved it! I know how you feel, sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees. It's not like the documentation of this library (Github Wiki I mean!) is particularly comprehensive either.

Comment: Yeah, it was hard to find anything for it... thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem. That's why I resorted to reading the source code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you just have a set of two separate events there, not recurring events (as in defined with an RRULE).

I think you would likely find what you need in `calendar.Events` instead (I've never used this library, just had a quick poke at the source code and it looks like the calendar class has an "Events" property).